# Remove IIS custom log field with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm trying to delete a custom log field on IIS using PowerShell. I'm using

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" -Filter "system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/logFile/customFields/add[logFieldName='TE']" -Name "." -AtIndex 0
```

But I get the following message:

```
WARNING: Target configuration object 'system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/logFile/customFields/add[logFieldName=TE] is not found at path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'.
```

How can I delete the custom field?

Comment: Can you get the property with [Get-WebConfigurationProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/get-webconfigurationproperty?view=win10-ps) and pipe it to Remove-WebConfigurationProperty? Like `$Property = Get-WebConfigurationProperty; $Property | Remove-WebConfigurationProperty` If `$Property` is `$null` then there is properly something wrong with your arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your approach will work or not, however you can easily remove custom log fields by:

- Getting the current value (a string containing a comma separated list of field names)
- Use Replace to remove the desired field-name and spare comma from the string
- Set the custom log field property to your updated field list.

In POSH:

```
$currentFields = Get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter System.Applicationhost/Sites/SiteDefaults/logfile -Name LogExtFileFlags

$currentFields = $currentFields.Replace(",TE", "");

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter System.Applicationhost/Sites/SiteDefaults/logfile -Name LogExtFileFlags -Value $currentFields
```

Answer (score 0):

For future refences:
The correct `Remove-WebConfigurationProperty` cmdlet to run is:

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty  -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/logFile/customFields" -name "." -AtElement @{logFieldName='TE'};
```

Just tested and it works